# Failing to understand recursion

Tags: python

New to Python and trying to understand recursion. I'm trying to make a program that prints out the number of times string 'key' is found in string 'target' using a recursive function, as in Problem 1 of the MIT intro course [problem set](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/pset3.pdf). I'm having a problem trying to figure out how the function will run. I've read the documentation and some tutorials on it, but does anyone have any tips on how to better comprehend recursion to help me fix this code?

```
from string import *

def countR(target,key):
    numb = 0
    if target.find(key) == -1:
        print numb
    else:
        numb +=1
        return countR(target[find(target,key):],key)

countR('ajdkhkfjsfkajslfajlfjsaiflaskfal','a')
```

Comment: `target.find(key)` and `find(target,key)`, are you sure?

Comment: @Mene well, it's a little inconsistent, but since `find` was imported from `string.*` it should work, no?

Comment: @Mene Ya, I should have kept consistency, but they should do the same thing, no?

Answer (score 8):

By recursion you want to split the problem into smaller sub-problems that you can solve independently and then combine their solution together to get the final solution.

In your case you can split the task in two parts: Checking where (if) first occurence of `key` exists and then counting recursively for the rest.

Is there a key in there:
 - No: Return 0.
 - Yes: Remove `key` and say that the number of keys is 1 + number of `key` in the rest

In Code:

```
def countR(target,key):
    if target.find(key) == -1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1+ countR(target[target.find(key)+len(key):],key)
```

**Edit**:
The following code then prints the desired result:

```
print(countR('ajdkhkfjsfkajslfajlfjsaiflaskfal','a'))
```

Comment: jepp... that answer is better than mine!

Comment: You're gonna enter an infinite recursion, since `find(target,key)` returns the first index of the key - that means `target[find(target,key):]` still contains that `key` substring you just found - as it's prefix.

Comment: Fair point. Cpoy-paste from above. Updated with `+key.length` to include key in the part to remove.

Comment: Contrary to what you might expect, Python's method for finding the length of a string or an array is `len(key)`, not `key.length`. Also, `find(target,key)` doesn't work - you need to write `target.find(key)`. Yea, Python is weird like that...

Comment: @IdanArye you're incorrect about `find`. Since the question imports `*` from `string`, we can assume that `(string.)find` exists and will work exactly as written.

Comment: @mariusnn: MMMmmm... You are right - when I checked it it didn't work, but I was using Python3. On 2.7 it works. At any rate, people should not use this form, since it's not compatible with Python3.

Comment: @IdanArye Not sure what causes this to break in python3. 
I guess it still shows the concept of recursion, which is what the question is about too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how recursion works. `numb` is useless - every time you enter the recursion, `numb` is created again as 0, so it can only be 0 or 1 - never the actual result you seek.

Recursion works by finding the answer the a smaller problem, and using it to solve the big problem. In this case, you need to find the number of appearances of the key in a string that does not contain the first appearance, and add 1 to it.

Also, you need to actually advance the slice so the string you just found won't appear again.

```
from string import *

def countR(target,key):
    if target.find(key) == -1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1+countR(target[target.find(key)+len(key):],key)

print(countR('ajdkhkfjsfkajslfajlfjsaiflaskfal','a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Most recursive functions that I've seen make a point of returning an interesting value upon which higher frames build. Your function doesn't do that, which is probably why it's confusing you. Here's a recursive function that gives you the factorial of an integer:

```
def factorial(n):
    """return the factorial of any positive integer n"""
    if n > 1:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    else:
        return 1 # Cheating a little bit by ignoring illegal values of n
```

The above function demonstrates what I'd call the "normal" kind of recursion – the value returned by inner frames is operated upon by outer frames.

Your function is a little unusual in that it:

1. Doesn't always return a value.
2. Outer frames don't do anything with the returned value of inner frames.

Let's see if we can refactor it to follow a more conventional recursion pattern. (Written as *spoiler* syntax so you can see if you can get it on your own, first):

> def countR(target,key):
>     idx = target.find(key)`
>     if idx > -1:
>         return 1 + countR(target[idx + 1:], key)
>     else:
>         return 0

Here, `countR` adds `1` each time it finds a target, and then recurs upon the remainder of the string. If it doesn't find a match it still returns a value, but it does two critical things:

1. When added to outer frames, doesn't change the value.
2. Doesn't recur any further.

(OK, so the critical things are things it *doesn't* do. You get the picture.)

Meta/Edit: Despite [this meta article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105735/how-can-i-put-a-whole-code-block-in-spoiler-text) it's apparently not possible to actually properly format code in spoiler text. So I'll leave it unformatted until that feature is fixed, or forever, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

If key is not found in target, print numb, else create a new string that starts after the the found occurrence (so cut away the beginning) and continue the search from there.